# class concept in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF and I need to group many components in one element and make and add new instance of that element in window for each student in database like 2 textblock plus 1 textbox for each student, how can i do something like that?

Comment: What are you having difficulties with? Have you tried anything? WPF is built on top of normal .NET, so you can use any regular .NET constructs with it.

Comment: You may want to look into the ListView control and using a DataTemplate for the ListView's ItemTemplate. This is WPF's equivalent of a Repeater control. Here's an [example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) on how to do this.

Comment: I want to have a structure that includes 3 textBlock and one textBox and for each student in my database add new to window, so teacher can enter students grade in textBox. number of students will be known in runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where WPF really shines - you can use an ItemTemplate or a DataTemplate to style the UI with the underlying data objects knowing absolutely nothing about how they are being presented.

Check out [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for an introduction. Effectively an ItemTemplate is a template (definition) of how each item should be rendered. A DataTemplate goes a step further and gives you the ability to select which template to use based on the data item being bound to, so you can have a list containing different types of objects yet still show them all in the same list/repeater control on the screen.